# Magento2 CE custom attribute with autocompletion

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to add a custom attribute at customer in Magento2 CE, which are shown in the Admin with autocompletion like the category for product?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean. If you are talking about a custom attribute with a predefined set of possible values, you could just use a "dropdown" or "multiselect" type attribute.

Otherwise, if you want to get "real" autosuggestions, for example from some kind of rest API, you would need to write that yourself.